# expectBody("", is(2)) vs expectBody(is(2))

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I was expecting this 2 invocations to produce the same result, however I'm getting different results.

```
expectBody("", is(2)) // empty path
expectBody(is(2))  // no path
```

My context is too big to copy here, but I got this example from the documenation. I'm using `expectBody` as shown here. However without a `""` path, my test is not passing.

I suppose there's a difference between these, but I can't find it in the [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.0/io/restassured/builder/ResponseSpecBuilder.html#expectBody-org.hamcrest.Matcher-).

I'm using v.3.1

```
ResponseSpecBuilder builder = new ResponseSpecBuilder();
builder.expectStatusCode(200);
builder.expectBody("", is(2));
ResponseSpecification responseSpec = builder.build();

when().
       get("/something").
then().
       spec(responseSpec).
```

Comment: This is something that I have never tried but I've read about this in the usage documentation of rest assured, Check if the below link helps

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#specification-re-use

Comment: That's where I got my example from by it doesn't address the issue of an empty path.